# Flex question: am I running in AIR or Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, browser, air, desktop

I have some common actionscript code, how can I determine if I'm running in AIR or in a web browser?
thanks,

Comment: Do you mean to ask "Am I running in Air or Flash"?  Flex is a framework that works in both.  In other words, Air and Flex are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I thought AIR is a desktop version that actually a web browser....

Answer (score 4):

use the flash.system.Capabilities object to find out if you running under AIR/Flash Player.

```
var isAir : Boolean = (Capabilities.playerType == "Desktop");
var isFlashPlayer : Boolean = (Capabilities.playerType == "StandAlone");
var isBrowser : Boolean = (Capabilities.playerType == "ActiveX" || Capabilities.playerType == "PlugIn");
var isOther : Boolean = (Capabilities.playerType == "External");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to use

```
flash.system.Capabilities

if( flash.system.Capabilities.playerType == "Desktop" ){
     trace('You are running AIR!');
}
```